# Custom Angular Directive, console logs, DOM updates, screen does not

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have been working with AngularJS for about 6 months now.  I am really pleased with it, but like with every framework there are some, "gotchas."  Mine is screen updates.  To level-set this question; I have been though all of the basics, $apply, $apply wrapped in a $timeout, etc. Even "transclusion," nothing changes the behavior.

I have been creating a "progress bar" using the Bootstrap CSS classes, and AngularJS as my application framework.

> I know, Angular-Bootstrap (ui.bootstrap) does this already, but it was exhibiting similar behavior, so I though I'd explore the problem myself.)

Here is the $timeout version of the code:

```
(function(angular, undefined){
    function progressTracker(){
        this.message = "Loading";
        this.current = 0;
        this.percent = 0;
        this.max = 100;
    }

    progressTracker.prototype.update = function (msg, max){
        if(this.current === 0 && !!max){
            this.max = max;
        }

        this.current++;
        this.percent = Math.ceil((this.current / this.max) * 100);  
        this.message = (msg || "") + " (" + this.percent + "%)";    
    };

    angular.module("myMod",[])

        .directive("noProgressbar", ['$timeout', function($timeout){

            var directive =  {
                restrict: "A",      
                link: function(scope, el, attr, ctrl){
                    function update(){
                        var p = el.children();
                        p.css("width", this.percent + "%");
                        p.attr("aria-valuenow", this.percent);
                        p.text(this.message);                                           
                    }

                    scope[attr.noProgressbar] = new progressTracker();

                    el.addClass("progress");
                    el.append('<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"/>');

                    scope.$watch(attr.noProgressbar + ".percent", function(newData, oldData, scope){
                        if(newData){        
                            $timeout(function(){scope.$root.$apply(update.bind(this))}.bind(this),10);                              
                        }
                    }.bind(scope[attr.noProgressbar]))

                }
            }
            return directive;
        }])         
})(angular);
```

Here is the HTML; the custom attribute no-progressbar is my Angular directive. `testProgress` is the name of the property to which I store my custom progress tracking object. Please note that this fragment was captured after the test ran. The CSS style "width" is changes many times during the test.

```
<div no-progressbar="testProgress" class="progress">        
    <div class="progress-bar" 
         role="progressbar" 
         aria-valuenow="100" 
         aria-valuemin="0" 
         aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%;">(100%)</div>
</div>
```

## PROBLEM:

While I can see the progress updates occurring in the debugger (Chrome); I see that the DOM is being updated (again Chrome debugger), I can set break points or output to the console and see the expected progress.  However the screen does not update at all until I resize the display. Then, the text message updates continuously, but the CSS changes are not reflected until I resize the display again, and again.

This seems really quirky to me, has anyone else experienced this behavior, have a solution, or see a flaw in my code?

Comment: Can we get a fiddle /plunker illustrating the problem?

Comment: Let me get that together. This was a snippet from a much larger project. However, to be honest that is about all there is to the code.

Comment: Without deeply inspecting your code I was having the same issue a couple of times and the main problem was that jQuery was slower than Angular which caused some problems with DOM manipulation.

Comment: @DonJuwe I am not using jQuery in my example, just AngularJS.  I am using jQuery in the real application as it also includes Kendo UI.  However, I am getting the same result.  I will be posting a JSBIN this morning.

Comment: A light version jQuery is also included in AngularJS by default.

Comment: Here is the Plunker.  However the problem does NOT exist when in Plunker.  I will explain in more detail in my answer I am about to post. http://embed.plnkr.co/TIB1NcwhFDH4mvNpXdfW/preview

Comment: Yes, AngularJS uses jQlite, when jQuery is also included, Angular uses that instead.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

So while creating a Plunker to share with this thread, I found that the problem does not exist out side of development environment. Once I saw this I realized this must be related to another issue I had while working with Bootstrap and AngularJS, in a Chrome browser.  For the sake of brevity here is a link to that thread on Git.

> [Form Controls take as much as 10 seconds to receive focus or update border css #15814](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15814)

The short of it is that, there is a bug with Chrome and dynamically updating CSS under certain, very specific conditions.  Once I removed my normal development environment from the equation, everything worked fine.

I guess this is the inverse of the, "It works on my machine conundrum!"

For those of you that have a need for such a progress control here is my code.

> [Progress Bar made from Bootstrap and 100% Pure AngularJS](http://embed.plnkr.co/TIB1NcwhFDH4mvNpXdfW/preview)